# Error "getData is not a function" when building form from existing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I'm currently working with form builder and am running into following error

> fb.actions.getData is not a function

Whenever I'm initiating the form builder from existing form data and then trying to save the form again afterwards (e.g. after making changes to the form.)

This is the code I'm using to build the (multi-page) form.

```
$.get(reqURL, function(res) {
    if (res && JSON.parse(res).success) {
        // Parse the data to render.
        var formData = JSON.parse(res).data;
        var formContainer = document.getElementById('formBuilder');
        var $formContainer = $(formContainer);
        $.each(formData, function (idx, val) {
            var jsonString;
            if (typeof(val) !== 'string') {
                val = val.toString();
                val = '[' + val + ']';
            }
            var bIsArray = false;
            $.each(JSON.parse(val), function (sub_idx, sub_val) {
                if (sub_idx === 0) {
                    jsonString = JSON.stringify(sub_val);
                } else {
                    jsonString = jsonString + ',' + JSON.stringify(sub_val);
                    bIsArray = true;
                }
            });
            var jsonFormData = JSON.parse('[' + jsonString + ']');
            jsonFormData = JSON.stringify(jsonFormData);
            var formRenderOpts = {
                formData: jsonFormData,
                dataType: 'json'
            };


            var $addPageTab = $('#add-page-tab');
            var tabCount = document.getElementById("tabs").children.length,
            tabId = "page-" + tabCount.toString(),
            $newPageTemplate = $(document.getElementById("new-page")),
            $newPage = $newPageTemplate
            .clone()
            .attr("id", tabId)
            .addClass("fb-editor"),
            $newTab = $addPageTab
            .clone()
            .removeAttr("id"),
            $tabLink = $("a", $newTab)
            .attr("href", "#" + tabId)
            .text("Seite " + tabCount);
            var $newInstance = $newPage.formBuilder(formRenderOpts);
            $newInstance.promise.then(function() {
                fbInstances.push($newInstance);
                $newPage.insertBefore($newPageTemplate);
                $newTab.insertBefore($addPageTab);
                $fbPages.tabs("refresh");
                $fbPages.tabs("option", "active", tabCount - 1);
                console.log($newInstance); // Returns {actions: {…}, promise: Promise} for the first page with actions being undefined and {actions: {…}} with actions defined for page 2
            });             
        });

    }
});
```

And this is the code I'm using to save the form:

```
$(document.getElementById("save-all")).click(function () {  
    const allData = fbInstances.map(fb => {
      console.log(fb.actions.getData()); // This line is throwing the error
      return fb.formData;
    });

    saveFormData(allData);
});
```

I've read different threads claiming I had to use the .getData() part in comination with a promise, but I can't get it to work for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fb.actions` is undefined when your `click` event occurs. Exactly why that is, we can't say from the code you've provided

Comment: I updated my first code block with a promise, however, the result of the instance after the promise was resolved is different each time (as pointed out in the comment in the code.) I cannot figure out why that would be.

Comment: The getData is only available after formBuilder has fully initialized.
formBuilder loads asynchronous and actions are not immediately available. --OR-- Could you please try with the upgraded version
 --formBuilder - 2.2.4
--jquery - 3.2.1
Follow link https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder/issues/462

Comment: I found the solution; it was a very simple error actually. I posted an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was editing a snippet of the first code block to the following:

```
var $newInstance = $newPage.formBuilder(formRenderOpts);
$newInstance.promise.then(function(instance) {
    fbInstances.push(instance);
    $newPage.insertBefore($newPageTemplate);
    $newTab.insertBefore($addPageTab);
    $fbPages.tabs("refresh");
    $fbPages.tabs("option", "active", tabCount - 1);
});
```

It wasn't adding the correct instance to the array.